# How to build a family of subsets with given properties?

Tags: algorithms, set-theory

Let $F$ be a finite family of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and define
$$F_n=\{\,A\in F\;:\; n\in A\,\}$$
Now, given a (wlog) non-decreasing sequence of natural numbers $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ which converges to $0$, how can we construct a finite family $F$ of fine sets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|F_n|=x_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

I am unable to do this in a consistent/algorithmic way. For some cases it can easily be done, but for some others any simple process produces duplicate sets and thus not a solution to my problem.

Assume that we are working with families equivalent up to reorderings of $\mathbb{N}$ so that wlog we can say $x_1\ge x_2\ge x_3\ge\dots$

Some questions:

1. What sequences $x_n:=|F_n|$ can be obtained from a family $F$ ? Can every seqence be obtained ? If not, how do you recognize a sequence that cannot be obtained ?
2. Is the mapping $F \mapsto (|F_n|)_{n=1}^\infty$ injective (bijective?). That is, if can two different families produce the same sequence ?
3. What if ask the following related question: given a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ can we construct a family $F$ such that $x_n=|F_n|$ and such that $F_n= F_m$ iff $n=m$ ?
4. What if we impose that $F$ be a topological space?
5. What if we impose only that $F$ is union-closed or intersection-closed?

I suppose 1 through 5 cant be done for some sizes of $F$ (in particular if $|F|<x_1$) but I don't know how the size of $F$ relates to the sizes of the $F_n$ under this circumstances.

The only approach that I thin I could make work is "pruning" $\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,\dots,N\})$ for some big $N$, but I don't know where to begin.

Thanks!!

Comment: It really looks like something that recursion can solve for you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila would you mind giving a hint? I can't come up with a solution through recursion

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer. Please, feel free to add.

Given a sequence $(x_n)$ there are at least $x_1$ sets in the family (suposing it exists) All sets of the family are different, so each of the $x_1$ sets to which $1$ belonng contains a new and different $n$. That is, $x_n=0$ cannot happen for $n\le x_1$.

The condition $x_n>0$ for $n\le x_1$ is necessary and sufficient for a family $F$ to exist: take for example que sequence $x_n=5,5,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,\dots$. A family can be constructed as follows:

\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c l }
5 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 &  &\\
\hline
1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & \rightarrow & \{1\}\\
1 & 2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & \rightarrow & \{1,2\}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & - & - & - & - & - & \rightarrow & \{1,2,3\}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & - & - & - & - & \rightarrow & \{1,2,3,4\}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & - & - & - & \rightarrow & \{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
- & 2 & - & - & 5 & 6 & - & - & \rightarrow & \{2,5,6\}\\
- & - & - & - & - & 6 & 7 & - & \rightarrow & \{6,7\}\\
- & - & - & - & - & - & - & 8 & \rightarrow & \{8\}
\end{array}

Observe that if there were less than five nonzero elements there would certainly be repeated sets.

This method produces $n^* + x_{n^*}-1$ sets, where $n^*$ is the last $n$ for which $x_n$ is nonzero. Also, the family of sets constructed has the additional property (3.) that $F_n=F_m$ iff $n=m$.

Without this condition, the sequence $1,1,1,1,0,0,\dots$ could correspond to the families
$$F=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$$
$$G=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$$